# Assign null to empty instance?

Tags: c#

I have an empty instance of an object which I assign values under certain conditions. If those conditions are not met I assign null to the instance, like the following:

```
SomeCustomClass someCustomClass = new SomeCustomClass();
if (myItem != null)
{
    someCustomClass.Id = myItem.Id;
}
else
{
    someCustomClass = null;
}
```

If `myItem` is null is it appropriate to assign null to someCustomClass?

Comment: can you add some more specific information about your case, this is too general

Comment: It is a general question since I want to know best practice. Thanx for asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be better to write it as follows:

```
SomeCustomClass someCustomClass = null; 
if (myItem != null) 
{   
    someCustomClass = new someCustomClass();  
    someCustomClass.Id = myItem.Id; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's no problem. But I would do it like this, so you only create the instance when needed:

```
SomeCustomClass someCustomClass = null;
if (myItem != null)
{
    someCustomClass = new SomeCustomClass();
    someCustomClass.Id = myItem.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't assign `someCustomClass` to null in the else condition. If `myItem` is null I would simply leave the Id property to its default value.

Answer (score 2):

Better:

```
SomeCustomClass someCustomClass = null;
if (myItem != null)
{
    someCustomClass = new SomeCustomClass();
    someCustomClass.Id = myItem.Id;
}
```